# The values for document.getElementById().value are null

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid, console.log

EDIT: It is working now. I had to get the values inside the function.

I'm trying to make a calculator that takes input from the user, calculates, and then displays the results in a table using javascript. The console tells me that the 3 user values are null even after clicking the calculate button and calling the calculate() function. The console log inside the function tells me it is getting called, but all the values are still null.
What I've got for html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Return on Investment Calculator</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="w3-container w3-center w3-blue-grey">
            <h1>Return on Investment</h1>
        </header>
        <br>
        <div class="w3-container w3-card-4 w3-sand">
            <label>Initial Capital</label><br>
            <input class="w3-border" type="text" style="width: 100%; height: 36px;" id="initCapital"><br>
            <label>Annual Return Percentage (Eg. enter 8.52 for 8.52%)</label><br>
            <input class="w3-border" type="text" style="width: 100%; height: 36px;" id="arp"><br>
            <label>Number of years</label><br>
            <input class="w3-border" type="text" style="width: 100%; height: 36px;" id="years"><br>
            <button class="w3-button w3-teal" id="button" onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="w3-container">
            <table class="w3-table w3-striped">
                <tr class="w3-blue-grey">
                    <th>Year</th>
                    <th>Return</th>
                    <th>End Value</th>
                    <th>Total Return Percentage</th>
                </tr>
                <div id="outputTable">
                
                </div>
            </table>
        </div>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
    
</html>
```

What I've got for javascript is:

```
var initialCapital = document.getElementById("initCapital").value;
console.log(initialCapital);
var arp = document.getElementById("arp").value;
console.log(arp);
var numYears = document.getElementById("years").value;
console.log(numYears);

var year = [];
var annualReturn = [];
var endValue = [];
var totalReturnPercentage = [arp];

function calculate(){
    console.log("Function is Working");
    for(var i = 0; i < numYears-1; i++){
        year.push(i);
        console.log(year[i]);
    }
    
}
console.log(year);
```

Comment: You need to fetch the values _in_ the `calculate` function. Presently they're set immediately when the script loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The console tells me that the 3 user values are null

The console *should* tell you they are empty strings.

> even after clicking the calculate button and calling the calculate() function.

You don't look at the values of the inputs inside that function.

You look at the copies you made of the values at the time the page was loaded (when they were empty strings).

If you want to read the values when the `calculate` function executes then you need to read them *inside* that function.